# How to give an index value to literals in lex and yacc?

Tags: c, yacc, lex

Say I have a grammar as follows:

```
dish: fruit type ';';
fruit: "apple" | "strawberry" | "pear";
type: "pie" | "cheesecake" | "flan";
```

...and I have a function to store these dishes:

```
bool storeDish(int fruit, int type);
```

How do I efficiently tell lex or yacc (I don't know which) that I want "apple" to have a value 0, "strawberry" to have a value 1, "pear" to have a value 2, "pie" to have value 0, "cheesecake" to have a value 1 and "flan" to have a value 2?

Comment: Why do you need to know exact values? You have to define non terminal symbols *dish*, *fruit* and *type* and terminal symbols *APPLE*, *STRAWBERRY*, *PEAR*, *PIE*, *CHEESECAKE* and *FLAN* in parser and it will generate values for each terminal symbol, and then in lexer, you have to recognize symbol (using regex for example) and return it's code to parser (something like: `"apple" { return Codes.APPLE }`). I mean that is how it should work in general, I don't quiet understand your intentions, you don't need to know exact codes for each symbol.

Comment: In my program I want to store internally each dish parsed as a pair of integers e.g. (0, 0) represents "apple pie".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a numeric type in a `%union`, define your nonterminals as that numeric type, store the values for each fruit and type then access them in your dish rule by index. An enum would be preferred but here is an example.

```
/* Define types, you will need to define one for each type of nonterminal */
%union
{
    int     numeric;
}

/* Specify the type of the nonterminal */
%type<numeric> fruit type

...

%%

...

/* Fruits value accessible by $1 and type by $2 */
dish
    : fruit type ';';
        { storeDish($1, $2); }
    ;

/* Assign each fruit and type a numeric value */
fruit
    : "apple" 
        { $$ = 0; }
    | "strawberry" 
        { $$ = 1; }
    | "pear"
        { $$ = 2; }
    ;
type
    : "pie" 
        { $$ = 0; }
    | "cheesecake"
        { $$ = 1; } 
    | "flan"
        { $$ = 2; }
    ;
```

http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/bison/bison_6.html#SEC53

Comment: `$` vars index from 1 not 0, so it should be `storeDish($1, $2);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, been a while since I had edit any bison grammar.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe, alternatively you can have yylex recognize the words, placing the enum value of the fruit seen in yylval and giving yacc the token FRUIT. The C code of the production(s) using FRUIT can now access what type of fruit was seen in yylval:

```
fruits:
    fruits fruit
    | fruit  
    ;
fruit : FRUIT           {if ($1==1) printf("seen strawberry\n"); }
```

(Note: my yacc is rusty; hope I made no errors.)